# Can't change spyder(3.2.4) keyboard shortcuts (installed via anaconda)

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I was trying to change my keyboard shortcuts in spyder(3.2.4) to be more reflective of R Studio.
Particularly I wanted to change "run selection" from <kbd>F9</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

However when I go to tools>preferences>keyboard_shortcuts the option to create a new shortcut is grayed out, and I'm not allowed to make a new entry (picture attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk4ns.png)).

I tried other keys as well just make sure and they all seem to be like that.

Has anyone else experienced this and is there a work around?  I was thinking it may be because I have spyder installed via anaconda, and spyder doesn't allow the change because there would be an issue with the source file and how loads from anaconda?

I've scoured the internet, including stackoverflow, but haven't found anything relevant to recent versions of spyder.  I know this was an issue before 3.0 launch a couple years ago (addressed by spyder developers throughout stackoverflow) but I didn't encounter anyone with similar issues with the past year, or on newer versions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your codes here.

Comment: I am using version 3.3.6 of spyder installed by `pip` on windows so it may be different but `ctrl+return` is used for `run cell` and maybe that is why you can not use it for `run selection`.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem is really a usability issue, which will be fixed in Spyder 4. The shortcut is not really grayed out, you just need to press the new shortcut in the dialog so it gets reassigned.

This is how things look in Spyder 4:

[image: shortcut dialog]